# Animating google map bouncing markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, knockout.js

Im trying to implement the bounce animation on to my markers, I followed the documentation for this and its only animating the the first marker in my array. i tried calling the locations on my markers into the event listener but that seems like its not working. Any suggestions?

here is my code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < locationArray().length; i++){
   var locations = locationArray()[i].location;
   var title = locationArray()[i].title;

   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: locations,
       map: map,
       title: title,
       icon: defaultMarker,
       animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
           });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', function(){
       if (marker.getAnimation() !== null) {
            marker.setAnimation(null);
         } else {
           marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
             }
            console.log(marker);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common mistake. You may think that loop binds a click event to each marker but actually it's not. Since click event occurs way after the creation of markers, it only works for the last one. You must pass the necessary parameters to a function and create the markers there.

BTW locationarray here is not a function just an array.

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ergec/8kdx7az6/

```js
 var map;
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", function() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_div"), {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.808678, -117.918921),
            zoom: 14,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        function createMarker(locationArray) {
            var locations = locationArray.location;
            var title = locationArray.title;
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: locations,
                map: map,
                title: title,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
            });
    
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                if (marker.getAnimation() !== null) {
                    marker.setAnimation(null);
                } else {
                    marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
                }
            });
        }
        locationArray = [
            {location: new google.maps.LatLng(33.808678, -117.918921), title: "1"},
            {location: new google.maps.LatLng(33.818038, -117.928492), title: "2"},
            {location: new google.maps.LatLng(33.803333, -117.915278), title: "3"}
        ];
        for (var i = 0; i < locationArray.length; i++) {
            createMarker(locationArray[i]);
        }
    });
```

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&v=3"></script>
   
    <div id="map_div" style="height: 400px;"></div>
```